# How to animate a (path) element inside an svg to scale larger and smaller without moving position visually

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I have an svg with a few elements that looks something like this:

[image: svg containing 3 circles and 2 paths]

I would like to create an animation where each element "pulses" (grows about 20% in size and then returns to its normal size without moving to a different position) one after the other, going around in a circle on repeat.

I began creating a css animation for this but my attempts to add a scale animation clearly were not using the correct center point because every scaling movement would shift that element to a different position as well.

I tried exploring different values for the property transform-origin, but none seemed to achieve the desired behaviour.

I have included a demo reprex that shows the behaviour:

```css
#Ellipse_1 {
  /* No transform-origin */
  animation: pulse 2s linear infinite alternate;
  animation-delay: 2.6s fill-opacity: 50%;
}

#Ellipse_2 {
  /* transform-origin same as circle's center location */
  transform-origin: 4 8;
  fill-opacity: 50%;
  animation: pulse 2s linear infinite alternate;
  animation-delay: 3.4s
}

#Ellipse_3 {
  /* Trying transform-origin center center keyword */
  transform-origin: center center;
  fill-opacity: 50%;
  animation: pulse 2s linear infinite alternate;
  animation-delay: 3s
}

#Path_1 {
  /* Trying transform-origin center keyword */
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: pulse 2s linear infinite alternate;
  animation-delay: 4s
}

#Path_2 {
  /* This goes off screen as soon as animation starts */
  animation: pulse 2s linear infinite alternate;
  animation-delay: 4s
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="shapes" data-name="shapes data" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-10 -10 100 100">
      <circle id="Ellipse_1" data-name="Ellipse 1" cx="2.083" cy="2.083" r="2.083" transform="translate(14 3)" fill="red"/>
      <path id="Path_1" data-name="Path 259" d="M60.749,74.282a103.267,103.267,0,0,0-5.686,23.5.459.459,0,0,1-.455.408H48.887a.46.46,0,0,1-.453-.38l-3.1-17.357a.458.458,0,0,1,.321-.519A75.754,75.754,0,0,0,60.24,73.846C60.708,73.591,60.936,73.783,60.749,74.282Z" transform="translate(-45.326 -63.944)" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="green"/>
      <circle id="Ellipse_2" data-name="Ellipse 2" cx="2.083" cy="2.083" r="2.083" transform="translate(4 8)" fill="blue"/>
      <circle id="Ellipse_3" data-name="Ellipse 3" cx="1.62" cy="1.62" r="1.62" transform="translate(21.942)" fill="green"/>
      <path id="Path_2" data-name="Path 2" d="M97.486,54.462C94.879,58.549,90.751,66.907,88.6,81.11a.6.6,0,0,1-.572.505,16.478,16.478,0,0,0-8.995,3.049.355.355,0,0,1-.562-.322,90.68,90.68,0,0,1,6.77-25.419.966.966,0,0,1,.352-.4q1.521-.866,3.1-1.629a.016.016,0,0,1,.009,0,50.611,50.611,0,0,1,8.261-3.124h0A.465.465,0,0,1,97.486,54.462Z" transform="translate(-66.545 -51.149)" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="red"/>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you "overwrite" the `transform` using CSS the `translate` is removed. Here I moved the transform/translate to a parent `<g>`. So each element is moved using the transform in `<g>` and then each element is scaled using CSS.

The circles are easy to scale because their origin is in the center already, but the other shapes need either to be moved so that 0,0 is in the center (change all values in the d attribute) or use `transform-origin` to move the origin. I guess that the result here is a combination - that could be optimized (up to you :-)).

```css
#Ellipse_1 {
  /* No transform-origin */
  animation: pulse 2s linear infinite alternate;
  animation-delay: 2.6s fill-opacity: 50%;
}

#Ellipse_2 {
  /* transform-origin same as circle's center location */
  fill-opacity: 50%;
  animation: pulse 2s linear infinite alternate;
  animation-delay: 3.4s
}

#Ellipse_3 {
  /* Trying transform-origin center center keyword */
  fill-opacity: 50%;
  animation: pulse 2s linear infinite alternate;
  animation-delay: 3s
}

#Path_1 {
  /* Trying transform-origin center keyword */
  transform-origin: 50px 80px;
  animation: pulse 2s linear infinite alternate;
  animation-delay: 4s
}

#Path_2 {
  /* This goes off screen as soon as animation starts */
  transform-origin: 80px 70px;
  animation: pulse 2s linear infinite alternate;
  animation-delay: 4s
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="shapes" data-name="shapes data" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <g transform="translate(14 3)">
    <circle id="Ellipse_1" data-name="Ellipse 1" cx="2.083" cy="2.083" r="2.083" fill="red"/>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(-45.326 -63.944)">
    <path id="Path_1" data-name="Path 259" d="M60.749,74.282a103.267,103.267,0,0,0-5.686,23.5.459.459,0,0,1-.455.408H48.887a.46.46,0,0,1-.453-.38l-3.1-17.357a.458.458,0,0,1,.321-.519A75.754,75.754,0,0,0,60.24,73.846C60.708,73.591,60.936,73.783,60.749,74.282Z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="green"/>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(4 10)">
    <circle id="Ellipse_2" data-name="Ellipse 2" r="2.083"  fill="blue"/>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(22 3)">
    <circle id="Ellipse_3" data-name="Ellipse 3" r="1.62"  fill="green"/>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(-66.545 -51.149)">
    <path id="Path_2" data-name="Path 2" d="M97.486,54.462C94.879,58.549,90.751,66.907,88.6,81.11a.6.6,0,0,1-.572.505,16.478,16.478,0,0,0-8.995,3.049.355.355,0,0,1-.562-.322,90.68,90.68,0,0,1,6.77-25.419.966.966,0,0,1,.352-.4q1.521-.866,3.1-1.629a.016.016,0,0,1,.009,0,50.611,50.611,0,0,1,8.261-3.124h0A.465.465,0,0,1,97.486,54.462Z"  fill-rule="evenodd" fill="red"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I was looking for. Can I ask how you determined the values for the transform-origin of the paths?

Comment: Hi @michael. That was just trial and error. I didn't know exactly how you would like it to pulse. But I this you should "replace" the 0,0 point of the path (maybe to the middle/the origin of the scale) so that you only have coordinates for translate, or something like that.